# How to filter django tables2 results for unique values of a specific column

Tags: python, django, django-tables2

I have a django tables2 table working pretty well where it only shows Querysets that have the correct Project Id. I need it to exclude Querysets that have duplicate user_id's though.

example:

user a, week 1, Project 1

user a, week 2, Project 1

user b, week 1, Project 1

display users that are assigned to Project 1. (needed result is table with rows a & b)

What I have so far:

```
#models.py
class Allocation(models.Model):
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(Resource)
    project_id = models.ForeignKey(Project)
    week = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    allocated_hours = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    actual_hours = models.IntegerField(default=0)

#tables.py
class Project_Resource_table(tables.Table):
    role = tables.Column(accessor='user_id.resource_type')
    name = tables.Column(accessor='user_id.resource_name')
    allocation = tables.Column(accessor='total_allocation')

class Meta:
    model = Allocation
    exclude = ('id', 'user_id', 'project_id', 'week', 'allocated_hours', 'actual_hours')
    sequence = ('role', 'name', 'allocation')


#view (project_profile.py)
def project_properties(request, offset):
    try:
        offset = int(offset)
    except ValueError:
        raise Http404()
    project = Project.objects.get(pk=offset)
    table = Project_Resource_table(Allocation.objects.filter(project_id=offset).order_by('user_id'))



return render(request, '../templates/copacity/project_profile.html', {
    'table': table,
    })
```

I have tried using set() but to no avail. Also tried distinct() but does not work with sqlite3 db. Also tried calculating with a function, but kept getting "Expected table or queryset, not function". Any suggestions on what else to try?

Comment: What doesn't work for the sqlite3/distinct combination?

Comment: The documentation says "On PostgreSQL only, you can pass positional arguments (*fields) in order to specify the names of fields to which the DISTINCT should apply. " I tried sqllite3, and mysql but neither worked. I tried a few work arounds, but finally decided to convert the project to  PostgreSQL. It works as expected with that database.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you either pass a QuerySet or a list of dicts when creating the table. If django-tables2 complains about getting a function, you are giving it a function, rather than the value returned from that function.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I agree with your statement but I was hoping that I could edit the Queryset with a function in an effort to duplicate the "DISTINCT" call on a sqllite3 db. I'm sure there is a way, but I finally gave up and just converted my db.